# Finding the integral of a square root

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is what I need to find

> $$4\int\sqrt{t^2-2}\ dt$$

Is there a way to find this without "guessing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is using integration by parts:
$$
I=\int\sqrt{t^2-a^2}dt=t\sqrt{t^2-a^2}-\int t \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}2tdt=t\sqrt{t^2-a^2}-\int \frac{t^2-a^2+a^2}{\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}dt=t\sqrt{t^2-a^2}-\int\sqrt{t^2-a^2}dt-a^2\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-a^2}}dt=t\sqrt{t^2-a^2}-I-a^2\ln|t+\sqrt{t^2-a^2}|,
$$
so 
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\left(t\sqrt{t^2-a^2}-a^2\ln|t+\sqrt{t^2-a^2}|\right)+C.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Method I:** Using direct formula:

As,$$\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2} dt = \frac12 x \sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\ln(\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x)+\text{constant}$$
So,
$$\int\sqrt{t^2-2} dt = \frac12 t \sqrt{t^2-2}-\ln(\sqrt{t^2-2}+t)+\text{constant}$$

---

**Method I:** Trigonometric substitution:

Let $t=\sqrt2\sec\theta\text{or }\sqrt2\csc\theta$
$$\int\sqrt{t^2-2} dt =\int\sqrt{2\sec^2\theta-2}.\sqrt2\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta\\
=2\int\sec\theta\tan^2\theta d\theta=2\int\sec\theta(1-\sec^2\theta) d\theta\\
=2\int(\sec\theta-\sec^3\theta)d\theta=...$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $t = \sqrt{2}\sec \theta$

Answer (score 0):

First get the expression in the integral into "trigonometric identity" form
$$\begin{array}{lll}
4\int\sqrt{t^2-2}dt&=&4\int\sqrt{\frac{2(t^2-2)}{2}}dt\\
&=&4\sqrt{2}\int\sqrt{\frac{t^2-2}{2}}dt\\
&=&4\sqrt{2}\int\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^2-1}dt\\
&=&4\sqrt{2}\int\sqrt{u^2-1}\sqrt{2}du\text{ where }u=\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\\
&=&8\int\sqrt{u^2-1}du\\
\end{array}$$
Then just do an inverse trigonometric substitution.

You may need to solve this integral at some point

$$\int\sec\theta d\theta$$
just multiply top and bottom by $\sec\theta+\tan\theta$
$$\int\sec\theta \frac{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}d\theta=\int \frac{\sec^2\theta+\sec\theta\tan\theta}{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}d\theta$$